# select box not working properly in IE9

Tags: css

In select box arrow_down.png image not come correctly in IE but in all browsers it comes correctly as it takes it's by default down arrow button how to make like this

the result in IE

[image]

I want in IE as how

[image]

```
<select id="Event-Type" class="custom-select w-select search-input event-type">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="First">First</option>
<option value="Second">Second</option>
<option value="Third">Third</option>
</select>
</div>


<style>
.selectbox-new {
    background: #fff url("../images/arrow_down.png") no-repeat scroll right center;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 32px;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    width: 175px;
}

.search-input.event-type {
    border-radius: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    width: 175px;
}

.selectbox-new select {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    border: medium none;
    box-shadow: none;
    width: 130px;
}
.search-input {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 7px;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
}
.w-input, .w-select {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    color: #555555;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 38px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: You can refer to this article on advanced CSS styling of HTML Select element: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/890021/Advanced-CSS-Styling-of-HTML-SELECT-Element. Best rgds,

Comment: this link still shows by default down button of IE not be hidden

Comment: See the working example of CSS-styled Select Element (to make sure that it's what you are looking for) : http://webinfocentral.com/download.aspx

Comment: yes i have seen but not working in IE9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plz try this one:

[Demo](http://cssdeck.com/labs/styling-select-box-with-css3)

```
<select id="Event-Type" class="custom-select w-select search-input event-type">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="First">First</option>
<option value="Second">Second</option>
<option value="Third">Third</option>
</select>
```

Comment: it's work but i need the same background color with same image is it possible

Comment: This option will be your best option.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
.selectbox-new::-ms-expand {display: none;} /*FOR IE*/
```

For detailed explanation refer to this article on advanced CSS styling of HTML Select element: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/890021/Advanced-CSS-Styling-of-HTML-SELECT-Element

Hope this may help. Best regads,

Comment: I'm using IE11 and it's working fine. Not sure about IE9. Rgds,

Comment: Well Jan. 2016, IE 10 and below will no longer be supported. So just block IE 9 lol, its crap.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith: Well said (upvoted)! Indeed, IE9 is like a stumbling block in entire IT domain :)